# Play any Flash livestream video directly from VLC

Tags: google-chrome, vlc-media-player, flash

Playing live Flash events in Chrome takes too much battery from my laptop. Can I play them in a native app, when I have just an HTML link with a Flash video embedded on the page?

Or is there a browser which is made specifically for that?

Comment: Just in case, can you give us an example link?

Comment: i'm not sure i understand the question because flash rendered in your browser is going to take the same computing power as if you were to run it from a "native app"

Comment: I think what can be optimised (e.g. h264 steams, usually called HD) are already hardware-accelerated (if option is not disabled in Flash settings). The FLV format can only be decoded by the CPU more or less.